# Is the weight of something being dropped the same as the force of something being static?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, statics, weight

If I have a block of let's say: 10 kg and I put it over my foot in a static manner, what we know from static mechanics is that my foot is opposing the weight of the 10 kg mass with the same force in opposite direction to maintain equilibrium, which would be around 100N. Now let's add some motion, and drop the 10 kg over a height of 30 cm for example. Why is my foot getting crushed? Isn't the same 100N of force I just withstood with ease in the static example? I know the object has more potential energy now but I can't wrap my head around the fact that the weight isn't changing and I am reacting with and opposing force of 100N in both cases. If the force is the same why the presence of height "adds" more weight. How can we explain this from a pure dynamic/kinematics perspective without using conservation of energy arguments?

Comment: "Isn't the same 100N of force I just withstood with ease in the static example?" No. You need to figure out the momentum of the block after having fallen from height 30cm, then you need to know how long it takes to come to an (abrupt) stop at your foot. Divide those two to get the impulse (the force you feel on your foot).

Comment: Why did this question get a downvote? OP is asking for an explanation of basic physics ideas. I think it's a good question, the type that should be encouraged.

Comment: @Not_Einstein  Exactly so. Conceptual.

Comment: @Not_Einstein You are entitled to your opinion that this is a "good question," but you are not entitled to foist your opinion on anyone else. I disagree. This is not a good question.

Comment: Related question: "I can place all the bullets I want on my foot, but it really really hurts when I shoot myself in the foot. Why?"

Comment: @hft  In what way am I fostering my opinion? I simply asked why it was downvoted.

Comment: @Not_Einstein And I *simply* stated that you are foisting your opinion on others. Why should I explain myself?

Comment: @Not_Einstein and hft   'Foster' is a less combative word than 'foist'. I expect you know that the similarity between the words is not accidental.

Comment: @Philip Wood   Ha, just a typo on my part.

Comment: @hft:  Honestly, your second example is also a "good question" in my book.  A good question is one that clearly articulates the asker's confusion and allows an answer that resolves it.  Just because the answer is obvious to someone who already knows the answer doesn't mean the question is bad.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert You are not the arbiter of what is good, and I reject your definition of a good question.

Answer (score 15):

Your foot brings the falling block rapidly to rest. Suppose the block has been dropped from a height of 0.90 m above the top of your foot. When it reaches the top of your foot it will be falling at 4.2 m s$^{-1}$. Your foot is fairly unyielding and will bring the block to rest in a very short time – say 0.10 s. The block's mean deceleration (that is its upward acceleration) will therefore be

$$\text{acceleration} = \frac{\text{change in velocity}}{\text{time taken to change}} =\frac{0-(-4.2)\text {m s}^{-1}}{0.10\ \text s} = 42\ \text{m s}^{-2}.$$  The mean upward force on the block during this deceleration will be

$$\text{Net force} = 10\ \text{kg} \times 42\ \text{m s}^{-2} = 420 \ \text{N}. $$

But the net force on the block is the upward force from your foot minus the pull of the Earth.

Therefore your foot must exert a force of 420 N + 98 N = 520 N (2 sig figs) on the block.
Your foot will therefore, according to Newton's third law,  experience a mean downward force of 520 N from the block. When the block has reached equilibrium it will exert a mere 98 N on your foot.

Comment: +1 Nicely demonstrated with a clear example. And BTW it also shows how crumple zones and bubble wrap work, increasing that time.

Comment: Should it not be 520?

Comment: htmlcoderexe Yes indeed.Many thanks.

Comment: I think if there is some kind of block with 520 N force, the case would be again the same as Gabriel mentioned.  In very simple term within conventional basis, its the impulse that is harming your foot, Gabriel.

Comment: I might be missing something, but how can downward acceleration be greater than g for a free falling object, and if gravity is causing the object to fall where is the extra force coming from?

Comment: @Questioningmind  Before it hits the shoe the block is in free-fall. I used $g=9.8 \text{m s}^{-2}$ to calculate the downward velocity of 4.2 m s$^{-1}$ after the 0.90 m fall. But the block is no longer in free-fall after it hits the shoe. It's being brought to rest very quickly by your shoe. Your shoe is exerting an upward force on the block. That force (minus the pull of gravity on the block) is what brings the block to rest – and in a very short time. [The block's loss of downward velocity as it is brought to rest constitutes an *upward* acceleration (in agreement with the upward force).]

Comment: I want to know what is that downward force, because the reaction force ( which is causing the object to stop) will be equal to the force the shoe experience. Is there any kind of " extra force " acting downwards or the force experienced is all due to the sudden change of momentum?

Comment: There is an INTERACTION between the shoe and the block. The block experiences an upward force from the shoe; the shoe experiences an equal and opposite force from the block. Neither force is primary (for which reason I'm not keen on the terms 'action' and 'reaction'. The origin of the forces is the squashing of the shoe (and foot) by the falling block, driving their atoms slightly closer together so that neighbouring atoms exert repulsive forces on each other. Suggest you now read up about the interatomic (or intermolecular) force curve.

Answer (score 5):

When the dropped block hits your foot, it has a certain amount of momentum, p. A force F(t) must be provided over a time interval to bring it to rest, where $\int F(t)$dt = p. The smaller the time interval, the larger the maximum force Fmax required. You have to apply Fmax + mg, to take account of the downward force of gravity, and it is that sum of forces that the block will exert on your foot. That sum is > mg.

Edited upon reading answer from @Philip Wood to take account of the block's weight.

Answer (score 5):

Weight is the force that the earth does on the block. It doesn't change if it is falling or not.

But the force that the block does on your feet is a different matter. If it is just there in a static equilibrium, it happens to be the equal to the weight.

But if it hit the feet after falling down, the feet does a force to decelerate its velocity to zero. That force depends on the instantaneous velocity of the block at the impact, and the time (crunching the flesh and bones) to stop. The feet obviously suffer the same force by the Newton's third law.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

After falling from height $h$ and impacting elastically with the spring (of constant k) the weight W and top part of spring travel down together by a common deflection $\delta$.

Equating work done to potential energy

$$ \frac12 k ~\delta^2= W(\delta+h) $$

$$\delta^2 -\frac{2W \delta}{k}-\frac{2Wh}{k}=0$$

The solution of quadratic with proper sign

$$ \delta= \frac{W}{k} +\sqrt{\left(\frac{W}{k}\right)^2 +  \frac{2Wh}{k}}$$

The result shows that even though $h=0$ ( true for a slowly introduced load) the effective deflection and in effect the force by load is double that of static load $ \dfrac{W}{k}$. It is even more when $h>0$.

Answer (score 0):

A true causation for your demonstration relies in the concept of Impulse. Discarding the conventional answer, if you want to go far beyond and evaluate the truth see https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323316385_A_new_course_of_relative_acceleration_within_Classical_regime .

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple. When a body is dropped from a certain height, the quantity of motion is involved. Another name for quantity of motion is linear momentum.
The change in linear momentum is equal to impulse. Impulse is nothing but a large force acting for a short period of time.
The impulse or impact is the cause for foot being crushed.